# Protecting Thiol group in presence of alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, alcohols, organosulfur-compounds, protecting-groups

[image]What protecting group can I use that will protect the thiol in the presence of an alcohol? Is there a set of conditions, or a group that I can use that is selective to the thiol over the alcohol?

I am converting an acid halide into an ester whose R group's terminal is a thiol. I will be using 3-Mercapto-1-propanol. I want to make sure that the acid only reacts with the alcohol side, so I can use the thiol group in the next step.

EDIT: I added the general reaction scheme for reference

Comment: How about oxidising it to the disulfide then running the (di)ester formation then reducing back to the thiol?  The disulfide is commercially available https://www.alfa-chemistry.com/cas_177854-95-4.htm

Comment: 2-Hydroxyethyldisulfide is [commercially available](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/380474?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8Ybx0drF_gIVWQFMCh0Opw2REAAYASAAEgKuR_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). You can use it as substrate for esterification and then reduce the resulting ester to thiols as Waylander suggested.